# Background execution icon on Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

On Unity, when it is executing something in background (like compiling code), a small rotating icon appears at the botton right. How can I call this same icon on my tasks on Unity Editor?

I'm doing some changes on the Unity Editor and it involves time consuming background activities, that's why I want to use the same icon to show "progress" to the user.

Comment: Do you know how long the activities will take? I mean do you know it's progress? Then I would actually recommend maybe the [`EditorUtility.DisplayProgressBar`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayProgressBar.html)

Comment: Not really, I'd like to have it on background, and DisplayProgressBar blocks the UI. Maybe I should implement my own.

Comment: well you can ofcourse simply use an [`GUI.DrawTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.DrawTexture.html) with either a GIF (you'll need it as webm) or single frames